# Use the sed command to search text file for entries 10000 and under

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use the `sed` command to search a file for all entries 10000 and under but I think this incomplete `sed` search string might be for entries 10000 and over:

```
sed -n "/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ q" logfile
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it using the following method:

```
$ sed -n "/^[0-9]\{0,4\}$\|10000/p" logfile
```

#### Example

Say I had a sample file, `logfile`, like so:

```
$ seq 9900 10050  | sed 's/$/ /' > logfile
```

This results in the file `logfile` looking like this:

```
$ head -5 logfile 
9900
9901
9902
9903
9904

$ tail -5 logfile 
10046
10047
10048
10049
10050
```

There's a trailing space after each of these lines thanks to the `sed 's/$/ /'` line above when we created the sample file.

Now when we run the above `sed` command:

```
$ sed -n "/^[0-9]\{1,4\}[^0-9]\|10000/p" logfile  | tail -5
9996 
9997 
9998 
9999 
10000
```

We get everything up to 10000, and nothing more.

#### How it works

The above `sed` works by finding lines that begin with a range of digits, 0-9, ranging in length between 1 up to 4. The notation to `sed`, `"/^[0-9]\{1,4\}[^0-9]` performs this part. The notation `[^0-9]` at the end there says characters that are not a 0-9. This stops `sed` from matching substrings in numbers that are longer.

The `\|10000` matches 10000 since it's a bit of a unique pattern compared to the rest of the strings up to it. The trailing `p` tells `sed` to print the results.

#### Using grep as an alternative

The use of `sed` isn't really the right tool for searching. You're likely better off to use `grep` for this instead.

```
$ grep "\b\([0-9]\{1,4\}\|10000\)\b" logfile | head -5
9900 
9901 
9902 
9903 
9904 

$ grep "\b\([0-9]\{1,4\}\|10000\)\b" logfile | tail -5
9996 
9997 
9998 
9999 
10000
```

The above will find all lines that contain a string of digits that are 10000 or below. The `\b` denotes a border either before or after the string.

Answer (score 2):

Perl can make this easier and more readable:

```
perl -nE 'say for grep { $_ <= 10_000 } /([0-9]+)/g' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/[0-9]/!d;/10000/q' <log.file
```

As long as the entries are in sequential order, you only need to specify that the line contain a number `!`else `d`elete it. And when you get to line `10000` you `q`uit. But 10000 is still printed - it will be the last line printed.

This would also be a lot better if you could anchor it - maybe to the beginning of the line like:

```
sed '/^[0-9]/!d;/^10000/q' <log.file
```

Which would be a surer - and faster - thing.

But, as slm points out, `grep` would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -nr "/0|[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?/p" logfile
```